# Angular 6, custom template for angular confirmation popover

Tags: angular, templates, directive

I have a problem and feel stupid about it so I need your help !

So I use this widget : https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-confirmation-popover/docs/directives/ConfirmationPopover.html

With this, we can set a custom template through "customTemplate: TemplateRef;"

But I didn't find how to define a global templateref for each components who use this widget.

```
<ng-template #customTemplate let-options="options">
   <div [class]="'popover ' + options.placement" style="display: block">
     My custom template
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

What i want is to define this template like a component and retrieve it without rewriting it.

Thank you very much for you help :)

Comment: Why not add that `ng-template` code in a separate component say `app-temp` and use that component selector wherever you want it like `<app-temp></app-temp>` And also what you mean by global `templateRef` for each component? I don't get that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact when we use this widget we use it like this : `<a mwlConfirmationPopover
           [popoverTitle]="popoverTitle"
           [popoverMessage]="popoverMessage"
           placement="left"
           (confirm)="****" [customTemplate]="app-box"
           (cancel)="cancelClicked = true" class="btn btn-danger text-white float-right ml-3">Delete</a>` we need to declare the customTemplate as the name of the templateref. But i don't want to write the ng-template in each components where I will use it, so I want to define the template and re-use it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the best way to do it but there is the "solution" I found :

A lambda component :

```
<button mwlConfirmationPopover
                    [popoverTitle]="popoverTitle"
                    [popoverMessage]="popoverMessage"
                    placement="left"
                    [customTemplate]="requestor"
                    (confirm)="delEquip(e._id)"
                    (cancel)="cancelClicked = true" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-trash" style="margin-right:5px;"></span> Delete</button>
<ng-template #requestor let-options="options"><app-box [options]="options"></app-box></ng-template>
```

and the template is :

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-box',
  templateUrl: './box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./box.component.css']
})
export class BoxComponent  {
  @Input() options: object;
  constructor() {}
}

 <div style="display: block">
    <div class="fond">
      <div class="boxAdd">
        <div class="card card-info" style="margin: 0 !important;">

          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> {{options.popoverTitle}}:</h3></div>
          <div class="card-body">
            {{options.popoverMessage}}
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="options.onConfirm({clickEvent: $event})">Confirm</button>
            <button  id="cancel" type="button" (click)="options.onCancel({clickEvent: $event})" class="btn btn-danger float-right">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```